# Swift Generics & Upcasting

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I've got a quick question regarding generics in Swift. The problem is I'm trying to store a variable that takes a generic as a parameter, but am unable to cast it up to the type it is restricted by. It's best explained in a short example:

```
class Foo { }

class Thing<T: Foo> {
    func produceBar() -> Bar {
        return Bar(aThing: self as! Thing<Foo>)
    }
}

class Bar {
    var thing: Thing<Foo>

    init(var aThing: Thing<Foo>) {
        self.thing = aThing
    }
}
```

The code above produces the error: `"Cast from Thing<T> to unrelated type Thing<Foo> always fails"`

Shouldn't it *never* fail, since T is restricted to being a subclass of Foo? I must be misunderstanding the way generics work in Swift, any guidance or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Swift generics are not covariant. That is to say, exactly what the error says: you can't automatically say a `Basket<Apple>` is a kind of `Basket<Fruit>` even if `Apple` is a kind of `Fruit`. There is good reason for this.

Consider the following code:

```
class Fruit {}
class Apple: Fruit {}
class Orange: Fruit {}

class Basket<T: Fruit> {
    private var items: [T]
    func add(item: T) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    init() {}
}

func addItem<T: Fruit>(var basket: Basket<T>, item: T) {
    basket.add(item)
}

let basket:Basket<Apple> = Basket()

addItem(basket as Basket<Fruit>, Orange())
```

This would be legal code if `Basket<Apple>` were considered a `Basket<Fruit>`, and I'd be allowed to add an orange to a basket of apples.

Comment: That is a good point, and makes sense why I shouldn't be able to do that. Thank you. Would you have any suggestions how I could store a variable in approximately the same way? Is there a possible/legal to say `var aThing: Thing<Any: Foo>`?

Comment: In your example, the problem is that `Thing` shouldn't be generic. It should just use subclasses (or better yet, a protocol). You never actually use `T` anywhere in the class. But it's not clear if your real problem is demonstrated in your example.

Comment: `let appleArray: Array<Apple> = [Apple()]
var fruitArray = appleArray as Array<Fruit>
fruitArray.append(Orange())` Ok! But why that works?

Comment: `appleArray as Array<Fruit>` in this case makes a copy that wraps each `Apple` in a protocol container, so `fruitArray` has a different layout than `appleArray` (and can't be `as` cast back to `[Apple]`). This is a very unfortunate ambiguity in `as`. In some cases it is a cast (i.e. it simply reinterprets a set of bytes as some other type), but in other cases it forces a conversion. These really should have different syntax, but they don't in Swift.

Comment: @RobNapier https://i.imgur.com/KZLxN9q.jpg

Here is an example (the image on the right) of generic Covariance. It accounts for the case you presented and throws a compile time error without entirely castrating generics in the process (see example of use on left).

Comment: @SacredGeometry I'm not sure I understand. The example you've given works precisely the same way in Swift (converted almost word-for-word; C# and Swift have a lot in common): https://gist.github.com/rnapier/e01a0e7a1e68317c4efea2732478df07. C# does have co-/contra-/in-variance (added in .NET 4), but the code you've given doesn't demonstrate it. The error you show in the right side is precisely the same as the one you get in Swift for the same reason. In both C# and Swift, Basket<Apple> is not a subtype of Basket<Fruit>.

Comment: C# does have ways to use variance, but they're not always safe the way Swift's implicit Array covariance is. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/index for discussion of that. I'm not sure if Swift will follow C#'s in/out system for covariance/contravariance declarations, or if it'll follow Scala's more explicit system, but I do expect it to add a variance system one day, like .NET did (it took .NET about 8 years to add it; I don't know how long it'll take Swift).

Comment: In swift it forces you to upcast to the base class (as far as I know) in c# it doesnt.

Edit: Just tested you code and it didnt. Not sure what went wrong when I tried to implement it in swift. I will investigate.