# Why do I need to force cast a property to a generic method with the same signature as the property?

Tags: swift, generics

This is my code:

```
class GenericClass<T: UITableViewCell> {

    let enumProperty = SomeEnum.myValue

    enum SomeEnum {
        case myValue
    }

    func callOtherClass() {
        OtherClass.handle(property: enumProperty) // Compile error
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    static func handle(property: GenericClass<UITableViewCell>.SomeEnum) {}
}
```

Why do I get the compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'GenericClass.SomeEnum' to expected
>   argument type 'GenericClass.SomeEnum'

Ofcourse, the fix would be adding the cast:

```
as! GenericClass<UITableViewCell>.SomeEnum
```

which results in this ugly code:

```
func callOtherClass() {
    OtherClass.handle(property: enumProperty) as! GenericClass<UITableViewCell>.SomeEnum
}
```

But why do I need to cast? `self` is defined as GenericClass where `T` always is a `UITableViewCell`. The method `handle` expects that signature.

**Is there any case this cast is needed because in some situations this will/can fail?** I would not expect Swift just randomly asking me to insert a force cast. I expect Swift can just infer the types and sees it is safe, but somehow, Swift doesn't agree with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `SomeEnum` is actually `GenericClass<T>.SomeEnum`. There's no promise that `T` is exactly `UITableViewCell`, so it's not compatible with `GenericClass<UITableViewCell>` ([generics are not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487258/swift-generics-upcasting)).

Typically in this case, what you want to do is move `SomeEnum` outside of `GenericClass`, since nothing about it is actually generic:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case myValue
}

class GenericClass<T: UITableViewCell> {

    let enumProperty = SomeEnum.myValue

    func callOtherClass() {
        OtherClass.handle(property: enumProperty) // Compile error
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    static func handle(property: SomeEnum) {}
}
```

But if there's a reason for it to be generic, see Robert Dresler's answer, which is how you would specialize the function correctly:

```
class OtherClass {
    static func handle<T: UITableViewCell>(property: GenericClass<T>.SomeEnum) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about how generics in swift are not covariant... interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Make your static method also generic and create generic constrain for parameter inheriting from `UITableViewCell`. Then use this generic parameter in method parameter

```
class OtherClass {
    static func handle<T: UITableViewCell>(property: GenericClass<T>.SomeEnum) {}
}
```

Comment: What is the difference of a generic constraint or putting all the constrains after the parameter name? Is there any documentation about this differences? This fixes the initial problem indeed, but I am still wondering why my code is having a hard time to compile.. Nice answer btw.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, I think that Rob explained it very well, so... ;)