# Generics types in VIPER subclassing. Cannot assign value of type 'ChildType' to type 'ParentType<Any>?'

Tags: ios, swift, generics, viper-architecture

I have VIPER architecture and I want to create parent VIPER search component that works with generic type. The idea is simple so I have search bar and I have table view. For example I can show drinks or foods names in table view. Depends on which generic data type I specified I want to show or foods or drinks.

I found [very good example](http://nikoyuwono.com/2016/12/07/generic-uiviewcontroller-swift/) that solves my issue with generic view controllers. But I want to create something similar for swift generic VIPER architecture.

I will skip describing all VIPER classes like (`Router`, `Interdictor` and etc).

So I have parent view controller:

```
BaseSearchViewController: UIViewController {
   var presenter: BaseSearchPresenter<Any>?
}
```

and child:

```
FoodSearchViewController: BaseSearchViewController {
}
```

This is a parent presenter specified in BaseSearchViewController

```
class BaseSearchPresenter<T> {
    var items [T]
}
```

also I have child food search presenter with a specific type Food I would like to display in my table:

```
class FoodSearchPresenter: BaseSearchPresenter<Food> {
}
```

When I try to configure my VIPER:

```
let viewController = FoodSearchViewController(...) // init VC
let presenter = FoodSearchPresenter()

viewController.presenter = presenter // assigning child FoodSearchPresenter instance to a BaseSearchViewController presenter variable leads to this error:

Cannot assign value of type 'FoodSearchPresenter' to type 'BaseSearchPresenter<Any>?'
```

Here is a [repo](https://github.com/matrosovDev/Generic-class-VIPER) with the issue.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487258/swift-generics-upcasting/30487474  Generics are not covariant. A `BaseSearchPresenter<Food>` is not a subtype of `BaseSearchPresenter<Any>`. (Let me know if you think it's not a dupe and there more of a question here than is answered over there.)

Comment: thanks for the link posted, yea I guess I need to read more about generics. The one thing I understood from the link adopting to my question that BaseSearchPresenter<Any> is not the same BaseSearchPresenter<Food> correct me if I am wrong. But still have a problem how to to implement it.

Comment: `viewController.presenter = presenter as? BaseSearchPresenter<Any>` if I do smth like that I have the same issue then as you've posted, maybe I did not get idea.

Comment: Yes, that will be the same problem. To the underlying question, you will need to go back to the actual problem you're solving in your code. Trying to build something abstractly generic is going to get you tied up in knots. Start by building your system with several concrete types; then extract the pieces where duplication occurs. Don't start with a generic class and try to force it. Start with a concrete implementation and extract a generic (ideally not a class…, but still something generic).

Comment: As I see you use class `Basket<T: Fruit>` , what you mean ideally not a class. Also I tried your code and compiler throw error at init method. not sure I understand what to do next ) thanks for help!

Comment: By "ideally not a class" I just mean that Swift typically encourages composition with protocols and value types rather than class inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left comments about how to attack this problem, but to your specific case, the answer is that BaseSearchViewController needs to be generic.

```
class BaseSearchPresenter<T> {
    var items: [T] = []
}

// BaseSearchViewController must be generic in order to vary its Element
class BaseSearchViewController<Element>: UIViewController {
    var presenter: BaseSearchPresenter<Element>?
}

struct Food {}

class FoodSearchPresenter: BaseSearchPresenter<Food> {}

class FoodSearchViewController: BaseSearchViewController<Food> {}

let viewController = FoodSearchViewController()
let presenter = FoodSearchPresenter()

viewController.presenter = presenter
```

To my point about starting concrete, I mean start with `FoodSearchViewController` as its own thing. Don't inherit from anything except `UIViewController`. Then build a second view controller that would make sense in this app and would need something similar. *Then* extract the commonality between them. This will tend to drive you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the answer, strange did the same an hour ago =) did not work for me and now it works. Posted to [repo](https://github.com/matrosovDev/Generic-class-VIPER) working variant if smith thanks for help!