# How to handle GenericClass<Any> for abstraction

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to figure out how to use generics instantiated with different types together as an abstraction.  For example, put them in one array or pass them to a function.  I know this is tricky because the objects need a concrete class at compile time.  However, experimenting with using  as the concrete class, I stumbled upon the playground code below.  Even if the class is instantiated as `Generic1<Any>`, the type of the underlying value property is correctly recognized.  So my mystery is this: how can `type(of: g1.value)` be `Int` even though `type(of:g1)` is `Generic1<Any>`? And given that it is, why can't I cast `g1` to `Generic1<Int>`?  Thanks!

```
class Generic1<T> {
    var value: T
    init(_ value:T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func handleGeneric(_ g: Generic1<Any>) {
    print("--------------------")
    print(type(of:g))
    print(type(of:g.value))
    print(g.value)
    print("--------------------")
}


let g1 = Generic1<Any>(1)
let g2 = Generic1<Any>("hello")

handleGeneric(g1)
handleGeneric(g2)
```

**Output**

```
--------------------
Generic1<Any>
Int
1
--------------------
--------------------
Generic1<Any>
String
hello
--------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can `type(of: g1.value)` be `Int` even though `type(of:g1)` is `Generic1<Any>`

`type(of:)` uses runtime type information (stored in the existential container that `Any` instances use) to give you the concrete type. I don't think it can ever return a super class, a protocol or anything besides the concrete type. The concrete type of `g1.value` is `Int`, and the concrete type of `g1` is `Generic<Any>`.

> why can't I cast `g1` to `Generic1<Int>`

Because Swift's generics are not covariant. That is, `C<A>` is not a subtype of `C<B>`, even if `A` is a subtype of `B`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30487474/3141234