# Mocking a class with generic parameter function inside Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, xctest

I am trying to unit test simple HttpClient behaviour. For that I have created an GenericHttpClientInterface protocol and concrete class GenericHttpClient that implements this protocol.

```
protocol GenericHttpClientInterface {
    func makeRequest<T: Decodable>(request: URLRequest) -> Observable<T>
}

class GenericHttpClient: GenericHttpClientInterface {
    func makeRequest<T: Decodable>(request: URLRequest) -> Observable<T> {
        return URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: request).jsonDecode(to: T.self)
    }
}
```

What I wanted to achieve is to mock that class :

```
class MockHttpClient: GenericHttpClientInterface {
    var invokedMakeRequestCount = 0
    var invokedMakeRequestParameters: (request: URLRequest, Void)?
    var stubbedMakeRequestResult: Observable<Any>!
    func makeRequest<T: Decodable>(request: URLRequest) -> Observable<T> {
        invokedMakeRequestCount += 1
        invokedMakeRequestParameters = (request, ())
        return stubbedMakeRequestResult as! Observable<T>;
    }
}
```

What gives ma a problem is that the method I am mocking has generic parameter T inside which is a class that the request will be decoded to. I don't know this parameter until I call this function so basically in MockHttpClient class for a property that stores stub data for makeRequest I've created:

`stubbedMakeRequestResult: Observable<Any>`

and after returning it I'm trying to cast that to result type Observable. This gives me an warning

```
Cast from 'Observable<Any>?' to unrelated type 'Observable<T>' always fails
```

and in consequence

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.
```

Any idea how to stub that data?

Example test that creates SIGABRT:

```
class GenericHttpTest: XCTestCase {
    
    var sut: Repository!
    var mockHttpClient: MockHttpClient!
    
    override func setUp() {
        mockHttpClient = MockHttpClient()
        sut = Repository(httpClient: mockHttpClient)
    }
        
    let test_mocked_data_stub = DataModelStruct(args: DataModelStruct.InsideModelStruct(foo1: "bar"))

    func test_should_return_mocked_data_from_mock_http_client() {
        mockHttpClient.stubbedMakeRequestResult = Observable.just(test_mocked_data_stub)
        
        let response = try! sut.getFooBar().toBlocking().first()

        XCTAssertEqual(response, test_mocked_data_stub)
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to understand the error - your stubbed type is different than the return type of `makeRequest`. So, you either need to create the stubbed data within `makeRequest` and check for the type. or you maybe overload `makeRequest` for the type that you are stubbing with

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that generics [are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30487474/1974224) in Swift, `Observable<Any>` will never ever be convertible to `Observable<T>`, unless `T` is `Any`. This is what cause your crash, as when you assign the value to `stubbedMakeRequestResult`, the concrete `Observable` is converted to `Observable<Any>`, and there's no turning point from here.

What you can do to avoid this is to make `stubbedMakeRequestResult` an `Any`, as this will not make any conversions behind the scenes. A small problem is that you loose the type safety and inference, but you can fix this stubbing via a function:

```swift
class MockHttpClient: GenericHttpClientInterface {
    ...
    var stubbedMakeRequestResult: Any!
    
    func stubMakeRequestResult<T>(_ result: Observable<T>) {
        stubbedMakeRequestResult = result
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: A bit shocked I'm the second person that wants to know this?