# Swift generic nesting

Tags: swift, generics

I want to convert a subclass with generics to a superclass, but it doesn't work. I really don't know where the problem is?

```
class People: NSObject {}
class Teacher: People {}
class BaseClass<T: People>: NSObject{
    init(_ model: T) {
        super.init()
        self.model = model
    }
    var model: T?
}
class SubClass<U: People>: BaseClass<U> {
    override init(_ model: U) {
        super.init ( model)
        self.subModel = model
    }
    var subModel: U?
}
class Tools: NSObject {
    static func transClass<M: People, T: BaseClass<M>>() -> T {
        let o = SubClass(Teacher()) as! T
        return o
    }
}
_ = Tools.transClass()
```

##### Problem complement

Thanks for @RobNapier answer! This helped me a little.
I ask this question is because that I want to implement code like this

Fake code:

```swift
class BaseCellModel: NSObject{}

class BaseTableCell<M: BaseCellModel>: UITableViewCell{
    func setCellData(_ data: M){}
}

class BaseTableViewDelegate: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    var dataSourceArr: [BaseCellModel] = [BaseCellModel]()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return CellTools.getCellWith(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, model: dataSourceArr[indexPath.row])
    }
}

class CellTools {
    static func getCellWith(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, model: BaseCellModel) -> BaseTableCell<BaseCellModel> {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BaseTableCell<BaseCellModel>
        cell.setCellData(model)
        return cell
    }
}
```

But when I got a SubTableCell inherit from BaseTableCell, the code is runing to

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BaseTableCell<BaseCellModel>`

It got error.

Whatever,  thank you very much.

(But I want to know if there is a better way to achieve the same effect.）

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     static func transClass<M: People, T: BaseClass<M>>() -> T {
>         let o = SubClass(Teacher()) as! T
>         return o
>     }
> ```

This function says that

- the **caller** can pick any type `M`, as long as `M` has `People` as a superclass, and
- the **caller** can pick any type `T`, as long as `T` has `BaseClass<M>` as a superclass, and
- the function will return an instance of the caller's chosen type `T`.

But that is not what the function does. The function always creates a `SubClass<Teacher>`, even when `M` is not `Teacher` and when `T` is not `SubClass<Teacher>`. Then you try to cast the `SubClass<Teacher>` to `T`, which fails at runtime unless `T` happens to be a type with `SubClass<Teacher>` as a superclass.

I don't know what you should do instead, because I don't know what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thanks  you very much! I known what you means. But what I don’t understand is that `SubClass` is a subclass of `BaseClass ` and `Teacher`  is a subclass of `People`,  I think It is an implementation like polymorphism,  like `aString as! NSObject`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments to rob mayoff, what you mean to return is always a subtype of `BaseClass<People>`, in which case you mean:

```
static func transClass() -> BaseClass<People> {
    let o = SubClass<People>(Teacher())
    return o
}
```

You need to pass `<People>` here explicitly because `BaseClass<Teacher>` is not a subtype of `BaseClass<People>`. [Generics are not covariant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487258/swift-generics-upcasting/30487474#30487474) But `SubClass<People>` is a subtype of `BaseClass<People>`. That's a normal class-inheritance relationship.

You could make this simpler to write by avoiding the temporary variable. Type-inference will do the work for you:

```
static func transClass() -> BaseClass<People> {
    SubClass(Teacher())
}
```

rob mayoff said it best, but just to reiterate, your current code says that the **caller** gets to decide what `M` is, and that the caller can demand **any** subtype of People. You didn't mean that.

Note that you should generally avoid this kind of nested inheritance + generics. It is very complicated and tricky to get right. Generally you should prefer simple (non-associatedtype) protocols over class inheritance when possible.

(That said, looking at what you seem to be doing here, I somewhat suspect that a protocol with associated type plus an extension is more likely what you want. We'd have to see why you want `model` and `subModel` here.)