# Check if object is of generic type with base generic type

Tags: swift, generics

With the following architecture:

```
protocol ProtocolA;

struct MyStruct : ProtocolA;

struct OtherStruct<some ProtocolA>;

let obj = OtherStruct<MyStruct>()
```

I want something like this

```
if obj is OtherStruct<any ProtocolA> {
 /// This dont work
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: This isn't possible. In fact `OtherStruct<MyStruct>` is not a subtype of `OtherStruct<any ProtocolA>` at all (and that's intentional), so even if the syntax were legal, the result would be `false`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487258/swift-generics-upcasting/30487474#30487474 for more) The correct answer is almost certainly "create a protocol that OtherStruct conforms to, and check for that." But we'd need to see what larger problem you're trying to solve to be certain. Often this indicates a deeper design problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a generic type using `some` since it should be a protocol the type has conform to and not the type itself. So the correct declaration of `OtherStruct` is

```
struct OtherStruct<Object: ProtocolA> {
    // ...
}
```

Then if want to check if an object is of type `OtherStruct` then this is implicitly done for instance in a generic function

```
func doSomething<T: ProtocolA>(with object: OtherStruct<T>) {
    // do stuff        
}
```

since doSomething can only be called with a generic type where the type parameter conforms to `ProtocolA`

```
doSomething(with: OtherStruct<MyStruct>()) // works
```

but not something else

```
doSomething(with: OtherStruct<String>()) // compilation error
```

And the same logic applies if we use `OtherStruct` as a property type in another type

```
struct Example<Object: ProtocolA> {
    var other: OtherStruct<Object>
}
```